# What's the idea behind the day starting with night?

Tags: time

I understand that the night preceding the day is from the Bible (for example, the description of Creation). What are some ideas that explain why the Torah sought to diverge from what most people's default would be: that the morning starts the day and the night concludes it?

For individuals who don't find morning beginning the day intuitive, I could rephrase the question as follows: Why would a very intentional G-d pick evening to begin as opposed to morning to be the start? I assume he didn't flip a celestial coin...

Comment: Just for the record: Sometimes in Judaism we have _the night follow the day_ - E.g.: many laws regarding eating sacrifices.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps because you can't appreciate the day without the night first. this is also the reason why we have this world which is compared to darkness and the next world afterwards.

see also [this](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/160961/jewish/Why-do-Jewish-holidays-begin-at-nightfall.htm)