# Significance of Torah day starting at sunset, vs secular day starting at sunrise

Tags: calendar, time, daytime

This is a very general question, and I hope for some general answers. However, in order to focus it, I would like to specify one point.

In the secular world, the day starts with "waking up" and ends with "going to sleep" (not the calendar day, but more in the psychological sense). In the Torah world, the day starts while we are awake, we then *go to sleep* for the first portion of the "day", and then we wake up, then continue the same day.

Are there any sources that discuss the ramifications of that? If that's too general, I'd at least like to know what the psychological ramifications are - what type of person does the secular way produce, what type of person does the Torah way produce?

Comment: What do you mean ramifications? If it's psychological, isn't that a psychology question not one about Judaism?

Comment: @robev Torah was speaking about psychology before the word psychology was invented

Comment: Bear in mind that regarding Kodshim eaten for one day, the night follows the day (the following night is permitted just like the day) see [here](https://dafyomi.co.il/pesachim/points/ps-ps-003.htm).

Comment: Closely related (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68509

Comment: Interesting question. Thanks! What I'm hearing from your suggestion is that the secular setup is based on the person's daily schedule, and the Torah setup is based on - something else.

Comment: I don’t understand the premise. 1. The secular date starts at “midnight” 12 o’clock. 2. Some halachic things start at sunrise (dawn actually)- fast days except YK and TbA. Calculating times for davening involves dividing the hours from daybreak to nightfall. So halachic things that involve daytime are set by, well, daytime.

Comment: @MichoelR That line of thought occurred to me too, baruch she'kavanti

Comment: @Damila true. My question could be clearer, it's overly general. For secular, midnight is the official start of the calendar day, and sunrise is the start of the day in a more psychological sense ("I begin my day with a coffee"). For Torah, start of the calendar day is sunset/nightfall, and I imagine for a FFB, in the psychological sense too. So at least for that specific question - how does this impact us psychologically - I think my point stands?

Comment: We also begin our day in the morning. That's why there are rules about eating before shacharit and not (to the same degree) before arvit.

Comment: @DoubleAA that concept arises from "day" as in "the sun is up" sense. Do you have a source that specifically frames it as _our_ day? Your point is good though, I'm going to think about it.

Comment: @RabbiK I don't know what you mean by "our" but it seems the same as starting your day with coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choshek struggled alone before receiving HaShem’s Or. Choshek eventually earns a Yod & Hei in its new name “Laylah” after HaShem’s Or affects its emptiness, as stated in Bereshiyt 1. | Asaf אָסָ֣ף also explains HaShem desired night to come first before day as stated אַתָּה ה֜כִינ֗וֹתָ מָאוֹר וָשָׁמֶשׁ in Tehillim 74:16.

If we recognize each day starts at night with Choshek, then we recognize the light of HaShem is needed to make each day Tov. - Otherwise HaShem’s light would be leaving us in darkness at the end of a secular day.

Answer (score 1):

"And God said: ‘Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for seasons, and for days and years; and let them be for lights in the firmament of the heaven to give light upon the earth.’ And it was so. And God made the two great lights: the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night; and the stars."

Bereshit 1:14-16 JPS 1917

Hashem designed that days should be determined by the two great lights.

"The heavens declare the glory of God,
And the firmament showeth His handiwork;
Day unto day uttereth speech,
And night unto night revealeth knowledge;
There is no speech, there are no words,
Neither is their voice heard.
Their line is gone out through all the earth,
And their words to the end of the world.
In them hath He set a tent for the sun,
Which is as a bridegroom coming out of his chamber,
And rejoiceth as a strong man to run his course."

Psalm 19:2-5 JPS 1917

The skies declare the glory of Hashem to all the world. When we acknowledge His work of causing the sun to rise and set by beginning and ending our days at those times, we give Him glory. Man does not determine when days begin and end-- Hashem turns off the lights, and turns them on to mark a new day, with new mercies every morning. Great is His faithfulness!